# Unable to build Shopizer

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I download latest source of Shopizer code from
 github.com/shopizer-ecommerce/shopizer
When i try to give build using Maven,I am getting following error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sm-shop: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.salesmanager:sm-shop:war:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.shopizer:sm-core:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project sm-shop: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.salesmanager:sm-shop:war:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.shopizer:sm-core:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies(LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:220)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install in your local repository the sm-core?

Try to go in sm-core folder and type

```
mvn install
```

Then go again in sm-shop folder and try to compile again.

**Update:**
Check your Maven version also (see in my comment)

Comment: Ya i tried to build sm-core,but i am getting error like below.[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mysema.maven:maven-apt-plugin:1.0.2:process (default) on project sm-core: null: MojoExecutionException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.mysema.maven:maven-apt-plugin:1.0.2:process (default) on project sm-core: null
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)

Comment: By the way the first error you wrote seems to be related to sm-core missing. So you first have to understand how to install it. What Maven version are you using? (try "mvn --version") Note that using mvn 3.0.5, making a "mvn install" on sm-core, then a "mvn compile" on sm-shop, it builds succesfully.

Comment: I'm happy. Please, sign my answer (that I'm going to edit) as "Solution" for your question... in this way other people with the same problem can understand what is the rigth way to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having problem in building shopizer project. I have downloaded the zip file from the github and imported zip file in NetBeans and I got the project structure like the below image.
[image: Structure of the project after importing in NetBeans IDE]

First I tried to build each modules that are sm-core, sm-core-model, sm-core-modules and sm-shop. When I did clean and build for sm-core-model, I am getting the error as

> Failed to execute goal on project sm-core: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.shopizer:sm-core:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.shopizer:sm-core-model:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT, com.shopizer:sm-core-modules:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.shopizer:sm-core-model:jar:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT in http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org.springframework.maven.snapshot has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

So how to clean and build this project.

Comment: I have solved this issue by changing in pom file to the target and source to the version of my JRE.

Answer (score -1):

You need to udate Maven project
Right clik on project -> Maven -> Update project